# Notice: Undefined index: fileToUpload in C:\wamp\www\upload.php on line 46

Tags: php, html, amazon-s3

I am trying to upload image files to an AWS S3 server using php. However, I keep getting this error.

```
Notice: Undefined index: fileToUpload in C:\wamp\www\upload.php on line 46

Notice: Undefined index: fileToUpload in C:\wamp\www\upload.php on line 51
```

Here is my code:

HTML(filename: up.html) :

```
{<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<form action="upload.php" method="post" ectype="multipart/form-data">
    Select image to upload:
    <input type="file" name="fileToUpload" id="fileToUpload">
    <input type="submit" value="Upload Image" name="submit">
</form>

</body>
</html>
```

PHP(filename: upload.php)

```
<?php

    require '../vendor/autoload.php';

    use Aws\S3\S3Client;
    use Aws\S3\Exception\S3Exception;
    // AWS Info
    $bucketName = 'bakemonoden1';
    $IAM_KEY = '******************';
    $IAM_SECRET = '***************************************';
    // Connect to AWS
    try {

        $s3 = S3Client::factory(
            array(
                'credentials' => array(
                    'key' => $IAM_KEY,
                    'secret' => $IAM_SECRET
                ),
                'version' => 'latest',
                'region'  => 'ca-central-1'
            )
        );
    } catch (Exception $e) {

        die("Error: " . $e->getMessage());
    }

    $keyName = 'test_example/' . basename($_FILES["fileToUpload"]['tmp_name']);
    $pathInS3 = 'https://s3.ca-central-1.amazonaws.com/' . $bucketName . '/' . $keyName;
    // Add it to S3
    try {
        // Uploaded:
        $file = $_FILES["fileToUpload"]['tmp_name'];
        $s3->putObject(
            array(
                'Bucket'=>$bucketName,
                'Key' =>  $keyName,
                'SourceFile' => $file,
                'StorageClass' => 'REDUCED_REDUNDANCY'
            )
        );
    } catch (S3Exception $e) {
        die('Error:' . $e->getMessage());
    } catch (Exception $e) {
        die('Error:' . $e->getMessage());
    }
    echo 'Done';

?>
```

Any help is appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Please remove the values for `$IAM_KEY` and `$IAM_SECRET` so you don't expose your bucket to unwanted actors.

Comment: What do you get when you `var_dump($_FILES)` ?

Comment: theres no error when dumping it. Heres the info I get:
C:\wamp\www\upload.php:33:
array (size=1)
  'fileToUpload' => 
    array (size=5)
      'name' => string 'pic4.jpg' (length=8)
      'type' => string 'image/jpeg' (length=10)
      'tmp_name' => string 'C:\wamp\tmp\php8EB.tmp' (length=22)
      'error' => int 0
      'size' => int 1849624

Comment: Heres the error i get after fixing the spelling error:
Error:Error executing "PutObject" on "https://bakemonoden1.s3.ca-central-1.amazonaws.com/test_example/php8EB.tmp"; AWS HTTP error: cURL error 60: SSL certificate problem: unable to get local issuer certificate (see http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/libcurl-errors.html)

Answer (score 0):

You have an error in the form, you forgot the 'n' in ectype="multipart/form-data" is enctype

Comment: And please, edit your question and **remove** your S3 credential

Comment: I fixed the error. Now i'm getting this one:
Error:Error executing "PutObject" on "https://bakemonoden1.s3.ca-central-1.amazonaws.com/test_example/php41CE.tmp"; AWS HTTP error: cURL error 60: SSL certificate problem: unable to get local issuer certificate (see http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/libcurl-errors.html)

Comment: Ok. Now that we've the fileToUpload and this is other problem. You need to install the certificate cacert.pem. This link maybe help you: https://docs.bolt.cm/3.5/howto/curl-ca-certificates

Comment: Thanks for the input. I've followed the instructions but the problem still persists.